# What is the smallest word size in 32bit architecture?

Tags: memory

Let's say I were to design a low level language, just for example. What is the actual smallest datatype for a variable I can have? Let's say for example the primitive boolean in java only needs 1 bit, what is the actual memory footprint (memory size) that it uses?

Comment: Lots of answers here pointing out that access at the bit level requires masking and shifting. That may be the case for the most popular processors, but I'm sure I've seen in the distant past a CPU that had instructions for setting, clearing, and testing individual bits. It would require a two-part addressing scheme though.

Answer (score 5):

The smallest directly addressable entity is the [*byte*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte), which is normally eight bits nowdays. Then nothing prevents you from packing multiple high-level-language booleans in there, but that would involve runtime overhead of shifting and masking, so it's a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could have a variable that only occupies 1 bit.
The compiler would then generate a code that gets one byte and gets the information out of it with bit manipulating (&, shift).

If you use some kind of compression to store the data and retrieve the data associated with that variable it could be even less than a bit...

Comment: Right, couldn't you just alloc 1 bit of memory and assign it 1 bit of data?

Comment: No, you can't, at least not under architectures which make bytes the smalles adressable unit (which are most these days).

Comment: @Nick Sure, but the memory allocator gets memory from the OS which gets memory from the processor, so how much memory you actually grab differs from how much you malloc. Also the standard libc malloc won't let you allocate less than a byte (or for that matter, anything that isn't an integer number of bytes), because the processor won't have a way of addressing anything less than a byte.

Comment: Who said you have to alloc? Works fine for global variables and variables on the stack.

Comment: I thought this is a theoretical question. You _could_ write a language that works the way I described.

Comment: @yi_H Very true. As you pointed out, behind the scenes an entire byte is still being used, but that byte can store (of course) up to 8 single-bit variables. So having a 1 bit variable instead of a 1 byte variable saves no memory; having several 1 bit variables instead of several 1 byte variables saves quite a bit. Compilers are great that way, they let us ignore most of the details about processor addressing (unless we want to use those details specifically in our code).

Answer (score 0):

Not all 32 bit processor architectures were created equal, and not all implementations of a given architecture have the same word size. It ultimately depends on the processor itself. 8, 16, and 32 bit word sizes are all common on 32 bit systems. Memory addresses are (usually--as Paul R pointed out below, systems exist where the smallest address is a word size) assigned every byte, which is usually 8 bits (though it doesn't have to be--I'm not aware of a non-theoretical architecture where it isn't, but I'm sure one exists). So the smallest amount of memory you can meaningfully allocate is 1 byte.

Comment: There are DSPs which will not address anything smaller than a word (typically 24 or 32 bits).

Comment: @Paul I had a feeling there were systems that wouldn't address by bytes, I just wasn't personally aware of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your target platform. The smallest addressable memory unit is 1 byte (8-bits) on x86. That being said, you can design your language to manipulate individual bits of a byte much like C and C++ bit fields do. However, under the hood the compiler needs to generate some fancy bit operations at the byte level to twiddle those bits.